# What does this LSB function do?

Tags: assembly

I have the following code which I think (but not 100% sure) computes the LSB of a given 64-bit integer.

Unfortunately, I don't understand the implementation. What is `bsfq`? What is `=r`?

```
static inline unsigned lsb(uint64_t b)
{
    size_t idx;
    __asm__("bsfq %1, %0": "=r"(idx): "rm"(b));
    return idx;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[BSF](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_19.html) finds the index of the lowest set bit, if there is any.

`q` is the operand-size suffix for AT&T syntax, which is redundant because the register destination operand implies a size anyway.

The `=` in `=r` is a [modifier](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html#Modifiers) saying that the register is overwritten. The `r` means it must be a register. `rm` can be a register or a memory operand.  See the [gcc inline-asm docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html#Using-Assembly-Language-with-C), and the [inline-assembly](/questions/tagged/inline-assembly) tag wiki.

I would recommend that you replace this by `__builtin_ffsll`, since the compiler can reason about that but not about inline assembly (apart from whatever it can tell from the constraints/clobbers).  (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)